# Получить случайное значение из двух возможных (Processing)

Tags: processing

```
int result = (boolean(int(random(1, 3)) % 2)) ? -1 : 1;
```

Собственно, вот. В result нужно либо 1, либо -1. Но есть ощущение, что почёсываю правое ухо левой рукой. Может быть есть способ покороче? Спасибо.

Comment: А что выдает random(1, 3) ?

Comment: Числа типа float в диапазоне от 1 до 3 (не включая 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тогда, если `random(0,2)` - `[0,2)`, `int(random(0,2))` - `[0,1]`, то, что ниже, - `[-1,1]`

```
int(random(0,2))*2-1
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает :)

Comment: Куда же оно денется :)